# Nested Perl Hash

Tags: perl, hash, casting, nested

I'm trying to take the value from the hash and use it as the key for the next level hash, this code works, but I am thinking there has to be a better way to do this.

Is there a way to avoid the K* array variables?

```
my @key = keys %data3;
my $deviceType = $key[0];
my @K = keys %{$data3 {$deviceType} };  ## Uber Ugly, find a better way.
my $measInfoID = $K[0]; 
my @K1 = keys %{$data3 {$deviceType} {$measInfoID}};
my $deviceID = $K1[0];
my @K2 = keys %{$data3 {$deviceType} {$measInfoID} {$deviceID}};
my $location = $K2[0];
my @K3 = %{$data3 {$deviceType} {$measInfoID} {$deviceID} {$location}};
my $measObjectLdn = $K3[0];

print ("Data: $deviceType, $measInfoID, $deviceID, $location, $measObjectLdn\n");
    foreach my $m ( keys %{ $data3 {$deviceType} {$measInfoID} {$deviceID} {$location} {$measObjectLdn} } ){
  print("OK: $m\n");
}
```

`%data3` looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = 'NTHLRFE';
$VAR2 = {
    'DIA' => {
        'NJBB-HLR-2' => {
            'NJBB' => {
                'LTE-1/DIA-1' => {
                    'DiaUnknownAVPs' => '0',
                    'DiaCerRejSysInOvl' => '0',
                    'DiaProtocolErrors' => '0',
                    'DiaWrongProtType' => '0',
                    'DiaMessageRcvd' => '0',
                    'DiaOctetSent' => '0',
                    'DiaCerRejPrNtInWhtLst' => '0',
                    'DiaOctetRcvd' => '0',
                    'DiaMessageDscrd' => '0',
                    'DiaCerRejConAvailable' => '0',
                    'DiaMessageSent' => '0',
                    'DiaCerRejMaxConExcd' => '0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to *do*? The values of `$K[0]`, `$K1[0]`, `$K2[0]`, `$K3[0]` are a lottery as hashes are unsorted. If all of the nested hashes have only a single element then you have chosen the wrong way to represent your data

Comment: Why have you called your hash `%data3`? It tells me nothing about its purpose at all

Comment: This appears to be a case of a bad choice of data structure.  If there's only ever 1 key in a hash, why do you need a nested hash at all?  Why aren't deviceType, measInfoID, deviceID, & location just keys in a single hashref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys aren't sorted, so the "first key" won't always be the same.

That said, if you want to compact this a bit, the following should work:

```
my $deviceType = (keys %data3)[0];
....
my $measInfoID = (keys $data3{$deviceType})[0];
....
my $deviceID = (keys $data3{$deviceType}{$measInfoID})[0];
```

This is ugly and I would not want to be the guy who comes after you reading this.

Keys will work on hash refs as well as hashes starting with Perl 5.14. If you're older than that, you'll just have to dereference into a full on hash.

Comment: You answered my question.  Thank you.Agree, it is ugly.  I was the guy who inherited this code.

Comment: Thanks -- just for future reference, you can surround things in ()s to create what's called "List Context", which acts like an array. It's what allows you to use the array index access without storing it in a variable -- much quicker. You could also surround with [] to create an arrayref instead, but I'm not sure it matters in this case.